# Why did I get -2 reputation for a question without a negative vote?

Tags: discussion

See this -

[image]

The question is *[How to count character and line from a string in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331744/how-to-count-character-and-line-from-a-string-in-assembly)*.

[image]

Comment: You got 1 up-vote for +5 and 1 down-vote for -2. In addition, you've now accepted the answer, for an additional +2. Thus, your a net reputation gain is 5 - 2 + 2 = +5. Your net question score is [1 (up-vote) - 1 (down-vote)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igeGM.png) [= 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I9eP.png).

Comment: @Makyen how do you know +1 and -1 in voting place as mentioned in your provided image?

Comment: @Makyen by your computation I get `+5` instead of `-2`.

Comment: It's a [feature that you get at 1,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). However, there's also a user script, [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](https://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) which will do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, +5 (total). However, each event will show separately in your reputation. The [timeline for your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/40331744/timeline) shows that the [up-vote was on 2016-10-30](//stackoverflow.com/posts/40331744/timeline#voteaggregate_636134687999999999) (for +5), whereas the downvote was on [2017-10-25](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40331744/timeline#voteaggregate_636445727999999999) (for -2). You accepted the answer today (for +2). Each event is separately listed on your [reputation tab](//stackoverflow.com/users/5697418/alhelal?tab=reputation).

Comment: You can also [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) to show how your rep is calculated.